# A way to clean specific strings after a language marker

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

Ok I have these strings in my db dump:

```
"[:nl]Some nl text here[:fr]Some french text here"
"[:nl]Some other nl text here[:fr]Some other french text here"
```

What I want to do is do a search replace on the dump and remove the strings that are after the `[:fr]` up until the closing double quote `"`, together with the tag itself `[:fr]`

Can someone provide regex that can do this?

Comment: Some tasks are best done in a 'real' language, not SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
select REPLACE('"[:nl]Some nl text here[:fr]Some french text here"', 
               SUBSTRING('"[:nl]Some nl text here[:fr]Some french text here"', 
                         LOCATE('[:fr]', '"[:nl]Some nl text here[:fr]Some french text here"'), LENGTH('"[:nl]Some nl text here[:fr]Some french text here"') - LOCATE('"', 
                          REVERSE('"[:nl]Some nl text here[:fr]Some french text here"')) - LOCATE('[:fr]', "[:nl]Some nl text here[:fr]Some french text here") + 2), '')
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/46493)**

**EDIT:**

Try this:

```
select substring_index('[:nl]Some nl text here[:fr]Some french text here','[:fr]',1)
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/46498)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not what I meant to do. I would like to do a simple string search replace with a regex on mysql source code and remove the parts of strings that start with `[:fr]`